# Convert a start string to target string using a given list of convertible words C++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I have a source string and I want to convert it into a target string in a given steps, like this:

```
"XO" --> "XXXO"
```

There is an array of words that can be converted and the targets, for example:

```
A={["XX", "XO"], ["XO", "OO"], ["O", "XX"]} (the word "XO" can be converted into "OO" and so on)
```

and with the given number of steps = 4, the conversion is possible:

```
"XO" --> "OO" --> "XXO" --> "XXXX" --> "XXXO"
```

So here I have a start string, a target string, a given steps and an array of words that can be converted, I want to check if the start string is convertible.

```
INPUT:
"XO"    "XXXO"    4
{["XX", "XO"], ["XO", "OO"], ["O", "XX"]}

OUTPUT:
POSSIBLE
```

Can you please help me and explain why you choose that algorithm? 
Any answer with example code in C++ is highly appreciated as I can have a clear view of the solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can't just post an assignment and request code.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Oh, I also think that is not appropriate, but right now I do not have any ideas to solve, so I just ask for algorithm and I will try myself.

Comment: Look into ```std::map``` for the dictionary, and you can just put output from dictionary into the input ```n``` number of times.

Comment: Depends very much on the nature of the set of transformations. Do you have more details?